# How can i create a padding between images in splited div?

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I split my container and put an image in each of them but when I add padding: 0 25px its not creating space between images. So is there any way to put 25px padding between photos/divs?

I tried to put margin and paddings in both html and CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.test {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1700px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="test clearfix">
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/560" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/560" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/560" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You example doesn't seem to be using any padding at all. If you add `padding: 25px;` to your css you aren't seeing any spacing between the images? Also you example is broken as the imgs referenced don't exist on SO, try replacing them with a placeholder from a site like https://placeholder.com/

Comment: Yeah when i put padding: 25px; I'm not seeing any space between example: https://prnt.sc/I2sObKoFnwyb

Comment: It may have to do with your `float:left;`, have you tried using a margin instead, it should achieve the same results. Try `margin: 0 25px;`.

Comment: Same with margins, not working, I fixed question so you can see all now.

Answer (score 1):

The float/clearfix hack shouldn't be used anymore. Use flex or grid to make your layout more "up to date".

Here is a solution with grid that creates a 25px gap between images:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1-3 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```